# accessing scope variable from a json object - angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I've a trouble accessing a scope variable from a json object (which is again a scope variable). Here is the code snippet.

**code inside of my controller**

```
$scope.myJsonObj = {
name: 'abcd',
details: $scope.getDetails()
};

$scope.getDetails = function () {
//some code
};
```

It says $scope.getDetails is not a function. Also I tried using this.getDetails() and ended up with same error.

Comment: You have to define $scope.getDetails() first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access a function not yet defined in `$scope`.

Therefore, you have to define `$scope.getDetails` first.